# Make Objects Appear and Disappear Blender 2.9

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation

I would like one of my objects to appear suddenly on frame 156. How would I do that in the latest version? I tried to press the eye to animate that but it said I couldn't animate it.

Comment: Does the object have only one material, or multiple materials?

Comment: @Christopher Bennett Just one. It's a cube

Comment: Eye is just for a Viewport, if you go to Outliner > Filter enable Camera icon that is for render. That is animatable as you tried with eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also keyframe the render visibility of the object even though it's not convenient to still see it in the viewport:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can mix the material of your object with a Transparent Shader, using a Value Node sent through a Greater Than (Math) Node with the threshold set to 156 (your desired frame) as a Mix Factor. You can then give the Value Node the value of `#frame` (just click the field and type it in), which will make it provide the value of whatever frame you are at. Your object will be transparent up until frame 156, at which point it will become visible.

[image: Frame]

Answer (score 0):

Use a [mask modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mask.html) on all vertices of the object and then add a keyframe at frame 1 on the Threshold value of 1, and a keyframe at frame 156 with a Threshold value of 0.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working... I set the Threshold to 1 at the beginning and the Threshold to 0 at 156 frames, but the object is not disappearing.

Comment: @yelement did you assign the vertices?  here is an example at:
   https://optionpeer.com/jimtpersonal/appearFrame156.blend
and perhaps I forgot to tell you that I set the "Interpolation Mode" to "Constant" as you'll see in the screencap at:
  https://optionpeer.com/jimtpersonal/cap1.png
did you also right click Threshold and select "Insert Keyframe"?